# How do I remove launchers from the KDE panel?

Tags: kde4, panel, sabayon

This question I would think would be far easier to answer by means of Googling it as it is so simple, but alas I am left to ask it here. What I would like to do is to remove launchers I no longer have need for on the KDE 4 panel in Sabayon.

[image: Screenshot from Sabayon 1507]
Here's a screenshot, down the bottom left you will see icons (which represent launchers) for Google Chrome, Terminator and Konsole, in that order. I would like to remove the Konsole launcher. The only solution I have managed to find on my own is removing the entire panel, creating a new panel and then adding the launchers I want and leaving out the launchers I don't want. As my list of launchers continues to grow this solution will only get more and more tedious with time, hence why I would prefer a simpler solution if anyone has one.

The most natural solution to me would be to right-click on the unwanted launcher and find an option to remove the launcher, but this is the menu I get from right-clicking the Konsole launcher:
[image]
Clicking "Icon Settings" just gives me this:
[image]
which is just the options for the desktop configuration file used for the Konsole launcher and to my knowledge has nothing to do with removing the launcher from the KDE panel.

Comment: Are you sure this is Plasma 5? It looks like KDE 4 to me, with the Oxygen theme? Also, I don't think Plasma 5 even has a launcher plasmoid yet.

Comment: I don't know KDE or Sabayon very well, but I know when I run updates every mention of KDE involves the number 5 and not 4 so I just assumed it was KDE 5. How do I find out whether it is KDE4/5?

Comment: I don't know Sabayon at all, but I think you can just run `kinfocenter` and it should tell you the KDE/Plasma version.

Comment: Aha, you were right it's 4.14.9. I will change my question accordingly, thanks.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

At least on my KDE4 desktop I can remove a launcher like this:

1. right-click on the right-most side of the panel and select `Unlock
   Widgets` in the popup menu
2. right-click again on the right-most side of the panel and select
   `Panel Settings` now displayed in the popup-menu
3. move mouse on the desired launcher icon and click on the `X` in its
   popup to remove the launcher (you can also click and drag it elsewhere if you want to)
4. right-click on the right-most side of the panel and select `Lock
   Widgets` in the popup menu (to prevent accidental panel changes)

Answer (score 4):

The accepted answer also works in KDE 5

*(to ascertain the version of your KDE: `Start Menu (alias Application Launcher) > All Application Selector along the Bottom > System (Cogwheel Icon) > Info Centre (Icon of an extension card) > [Get a new Dialog] > About System on the left)*

Inspired by [Kde Plasma 5: How To Add And Remove A Widget From Panel In Kde](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4j8aQ.png):

Right-click on the panel or an icon in the panel. You will get the option to "UNLOCK WIDGETS"

[image: UNLOCK WIDGETS]

Now a "Toolbox" Icon appears at desktop's bottom right (actually looks like a stylized Royale with Cheese or a stack of Oreos.)

[image: A TOOLBOX ICON APPEARS]

Right-click on the toolbox icon and select "Panel Settings" (or just left-click on the toolbox icon directly). A puzzling configuration element appears (above the panel if said panel is on the bottom of the screen.)

[image: A PUZZLING CONFIGURATION ELEMENT APPEARS]

Now move the mouse pointer to the icon you want to remove. A pop-up menu with a kill button appears. You can also right-click on the icon, then a pop-menu with the option "Remove this icon" appears.

[image: A KILL OPTION APPEARS]

Do the expected thing. You are then notified that the icon has been removed!

[image: THE ICON VANISHES]

After that, lock the widgets again.

[image: LOCK THIS STUFF, YO!]

Phew.

(IMHO, this is what happens when overdesign takes hold. It would be better to have a separate management interface with a "time machine" to have rollback functionality somewhere in System Settings. Then the lock/unlock (mis)feature would be wholly unnecessary too (I vaguely remember this from KDE 3 maybe).)

Answer (score 0):

In KDE Plasma 5.8 LTS on Debian Stretch you have to click the hamburger icon (three horizontal lines) at the far RIGHT side of the Panel. You then get into a mode like this where you can remove the icons. This user hostile experience is guaranteed to persist for a long time as this is the kind of brilliant engineering that goes into "LTS" (long term support) editions of KDE Plasma.

[image: unbelievably brilliant UX]

After you have this special "I can haz change my panel" mode open, you can has little red X icons and can remove things from your launcher panel (task bar).