# Remove an icon from KDE Icons-only Task Manager

Tags: kde, plasma

KDE added a KMines icon to my (or should I say, our) Icons-only Task Manager in my panel.

I'd like to remove said icon but I cannot see (my fault? probably) any way to do so, hence I googled and I've found [Remove icons from KDE taskbar](https://superuser.com/questions/385126/remove-icons-from-kde-task-manager) but the question and its answers are old and KDE is sort of a moving target… in other words, no one of the accepted/upvoted answers is working for me now.

I use SUSE Tumbleweed so I guess I'm on a fairly recent release of KDE.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/215016/40327

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When pinned to the task manager: Right-click on the icon > Unpin from Task Manager

When pinned to the panel: Right-click on panel > Enter Edit Mode > Hover over icon > Remove

Comment: Only offers "Pin" for unpinned, but when it's pinned it doesn't offer "Unpin".

Comment: Sounds like you didn't pin it to the task manager but to the panel. See my edit.

Comment: See the link below the original question. That worked for me.

Comment: Meglio tardi che mai.